# Pass variable from custom module to twig template

Tags: theming

How can I pass a variable from my custom module to a twig field template?

my field template is the "field--node--field-webform--parliament-visit.html.twig"

and my module is named as "custommodule"

I tried this function according to documentation but apparently I didnt understand smth correctly:

```
  function custommodule_preprocess_field_node_field_webform_parliament_visit(array &$variables) {
    $VARIABLE_NAME = 'my_variable';
    $variables['varname'] = $VARIABLE_NAME ;
  }
```

Comment: I think the hook function should be named `custommodule_preprocess_field_node_field_webform_parliament_visit` change `logintosubmit` by your module name `custommodule` and don't forget to flush all cache.

Comment: Thanks I ll try that...I was just wondering also where should I place this function. Is it ok if I place it inside my custommoduleBlock.php file or I have to place it only in .module file?

Comment: @DimitrisMarkopoulos all hooks must go in .module file, with the exception of preprocess & alter hooks. Those can altenatively go inside your theme's .theme file. Thus, you can place this one in .module file or in .theme file.

Comment: You should have two underscores where there are two hyphens in the twig file name, so `custommodule_preprocess_field__node__field_webform__parliament_visit`.

Comment: @othermachines thanks! that did the trick!